# Why my view with if statement won't work fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this output. the number shown in output is `post.user.id`.
Bubble should be switched back and forth if it was different id.
But it judges it's the same person even if it's not.
Why?

**Current Output**

```
2            Good, you?          > Person B
1            How have you been?  > person A
2            What's up?          > person B
Person A < Hello!!!!               1
```

**I wasnt this Output**

```
2            Good, you?          > Person B
Person A < How have you been?      1
2            What's up?          > person B
Person A < Hello!!!!               1
```

**View**

```
<% who = "" %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <tr id="<%= dom_post_id(post) %>">

        <% if post.user.id == who %>
            <td><%= post.user.nickname if post.user %></td>
            <td><div class="bubble me"><%= post.body %></div></td>
            <td><%= post.user.id %></td>
        <% else %>
            <td><%= post.user.id %></td>
            <td><div class="bubble you"><%= post.body %></div></td>
            <td><%= post.user.nickname if post.user %></td>     
        <% end %>
    </tr>
    <% who = post.user.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think it might be because you are setting `who = post.user.id` at the end of the loop. This sets `who` to the owner of the current post, but then the next post is the other user. So the if statement is failing and going into the else block.

Comment: I agree but I don't understand why the last output displays Person A in the first column

Comment: Yea, I'm lost on that too...

Comment: looking at the post.body. I think the last message is the first output. But then how is Person A displayed again.

Comment: write a method for current_user which gives you the id of the signed in user. Then replace "who" and use current_user instead.
So your if will be <% if current_user == post.user_id %>

Comment: @Wasi Thanks. I'm assuming that non-registered user might be watching this post. so I decided not to use current_user

Comment: My only guess is that somehow the very first post (the last output, because it appears that they are being outputted in descending order by date) did not receive a user id. But that's probably a problem elsewhere. Your suggestion should fix the rest.

Comment: @Foo if you're expecting unregistered users, would it be possible to get the id within the first post, and set `who` to that id? Because that should have the same effect.

Comment: @Foo, Also why don't you just display the nicknames. Why do you want to display the id?

Comment: @jonhopkins what do you mean by getting the id within the first post?

Comment: @Was I'm just testing for now to check whether if id is different or not. that's the only reason. I'll replace it with nickname

Comment: @Foo something like `<% if who == "" %> <% who = post.user.id %> <% end %>` at the top of the loop. This will set `who` to the id of the first post, and then it should display all the posts with that id as having the nickname on the left.

Comment: @jonhopkins could you show me an example in answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor your code like this:

```
<% user_id_for_left_side = @posts.first.try(:user_id) %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

  <tr id="<%= dom_post_id(post) %>">    
    <% if post.user_id == user_id_for_left_side %>
      <td><%= post.user.nickname %></td>
      <td><div class="bubble me"><%= post.body %></div></td>
      <td><%= post.user_id %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td><%= post.user_id %></td>
      <td><div class="bubble you"><%= post.body %></div></td>
      <td><%= post.user.nickname %></td>     
    <% end %>
  </tr>

<% end %>
```

**Why using `post.user_id` instead of `post.user.id` ?**
Because doing `post.user_id` is using less resources than `post.user.id`.

**Why deleting `if post.user` ?**
It is implicit that every Post belongs to a User (you should have a presence validation on Post model for the attribute `user_id`). This means a post always have a user associated with,  no need to check for its presence.

Comment: This will still result in all the posts being displayed with the nickname on the right.

Comment: The result is still the same

Comment: add a `<td><%= last_user_id %></td>` to debug and see if it has the expected behavior

Comment: @MrYoshiji as I wrote in my Question. It's still current output.  id#1 and #2 are in the list. But it won't follow our rule.

Comment: @Foo I would go with this answer now. It gets the correct id outside of the loop, doesn't perform a redundant check inside each iteration of the loop, and is refactored in a clear manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% who = -1 %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

    <% if who == -1 %>
        <% who = post.user.id %>
    <% end %>

    <tr id="<%= dom_post_id(post) %>">

        <% if post.user.id == who %>
            <td><%= post.user.nickname if post.user %></td>
            <td><div class="bubble me"><%= post.body %></div></td>
            <td><%= post.user.id %></td>
        <% else %>
            <td><%= post.user.id %></td>
            <td><div class="bubble you"><%= post.body %></div></td>
            <td><%= post.user.nickname if post.user %></td>     
        <% end %>
    </tr>

<% end %>
```

The added `if` block will set the variable `who` to the id of the user of the first post the loop encounters, and then not set it again. In every iteration of the loop after that, `post.user.id` will be `who` every time the post has that id, and the nickname will be on the left. For the posts with a different id, the nickname will be on the right.

Comment: Bad idea to compare who with -1 at every loop. It is useless

Comment: @MrYoshiji It's useful the first iteration. And I've never used Ruby before, so I don't know anything about its collections, or how to get a property out of the first item in `@posts`. If you can suggest a better solution with the same effect, I will gladly give you credit where it is due.

Comment: I agree with MrYoshiji.  you can use @posts.first to get the first.

Comment: ahhhhhh!!! Now it works fine why!?!??!? Is there anyway to do this with more beautiful code?

Comment: @Foo possibly. If D3mon-1stVFW or MrYoshiji can suggest something better, I will update the answer.